# How to update RecyclerView from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, broadcastreceiver

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I have a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsMonitor">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-100">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my `MainActivity`, I have `RecyclerView` with a list of received SMS.

My question is - How I can update the `RecyclerView` from my `BroadcastReceiver` "SmsMonitor" in case new SMS received when the application is running?

UPD: I mean I need solution for both states - for running application AND for state when application is not running, in one receiver. Because I have to take SMS all time while phone is working. And in case the application is running I want to update `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do it through the `Service`, but I did not succeed.
But I found simple solution:

I still have `BroadcastReceiver` `SmsMonitor`, registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`

And in the point where I create instance of my `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(this);
```

After this I register another `BroadcastReceviver`:

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        setInitialData();
        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

And in `setInitialData()` I recreate all list of data for `RecyclerView`.

And now I have two independently working `BroadcastReceiver`. The first working the `BroadcastReceiver` from the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and then working the `BroadcastReceiver` registered in MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `BrodcastReceiver` in your `MainActivity` or `Fragment` as well which hosts the `RecyclerView`. So that when the new SMS is received, you can call the `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter of your `RecyclerView` to update it.

Declare a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` like the following. This can be an inner class of your `MainActivity` class.

```
class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    // Update your RecyclerView here 
                    // by calling notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Now create an instance of this `BroadcastReceiver` in the `onCreate` function of your `MainActivity` and register the receiver.

You need to ask for SMS permission first in your `Activity` like the following.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 0);
} else {
        // register sms receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    } else {
        // register sms receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to un-register the receiver in the `onDestroy` function of your `MainActivity`.

Hope that helps!

**Update**

Based on the comment below this answer, you have two cases.

Case 1. The app is running.
 Case 2. The app is not running.

For case 1: The local `BroadcastReceiver` like I shown above, is good enough to update the `RecyclerView` instantly when a new SMS arrives. As you are handling the `BroadcastReceiver` from the `MainActivity` this should not be a problem, as you have the reference to your `RecyclerView`.

Now for Case 2: If you are able to detect any new SMS arrival, you can save the new SMS received in your local database. You need to have an SQLite database for your application which will store all the SMS and the `RecyclerView` in your application should populate the data from the database table where the SMS are stored. I hope you get the idea - just store the SMS in your local database associated with your application and when you run the application and launch the `MainActivity`, read the SMS from your local database and show them in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question.
You solution will receive SMS only then application is runing. But I need to receive SMS all time while phone is working. Not only when app is running.

Comment: I think you asked for receiving SMS while the app is running. However, you can look into the [JobScheduler](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html) to get to know how you can read SMS when your application is not running.

Comment: I already write app to receive SMS during my app not running. And I understand how I can receive SMS into app. I asked how do I combine these to solution? And I think this will be bad idea to write two receivers - one for app not running and one for into app. I want write only one receive for both solution.

Comment: Actually, you are not writing a receiver when the application is not running. From Android Oreo, you cannot run background services as you did before maybe. You need to implement a `JobScheduler` that I mentioned earlier to get the new SMS and then having a single `BroadcastReceiver` while the app is running will suffice.

Comment: In general, I'm trying to write an application for receiving SMS, which should replace the standard application. And I want to be like standart application - then app is running, during receive new SMS it show on screen, but then app not running, show notification. And yes, I already write code code for both case, but I dont understand how to link the `BroadcastReciever` for notification and `RecyclerView` in application.

Comment: Can you please check the updated answer? Please let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you for you time, but I think this is not good idea, to duplicate information. It will require writing a wrapper about checking state change of any sms, delete, etc.

Comment: A see one solution, but it not like me. In `BroadcastReceiver` start/bind to `service` and send to them information about new sms. And at application start - also bind to this `service`. And in the `service` have check - if app is binding, send to them a singal about new sms. And in app process this signal and update `RecyclerView`.

Comment: This solution will be work, but I hope to find simpler solution.